# Not able to clear cookies properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

Hi my application has two types of login's one is facebook and other is normal log in. To differentiate between them and bring the values accordingly i have used cookies and clearing those in logout event like this.

But when i login through email and password and then logout and again log in through Fb the UserCookie cookie is still persisting and its entering to the first if statement again

```
  public ActionResult Logout(string returnUrl = "/")
    {
        try
        {

            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (Request.Cookies["UserCookie"] != null)
            {

                Request.Cookies["UserCookie"].Expires = DateTime.Now;
                Request.Cookies["UserCookie"].Value = "";
            }
            if (Request.Cookies["fbUserUserID"] != null)
            {
                Request.Cookies["fbUserUserID"].Expires = DateTime.Now;
                Request.Cookies["fbUserUserID"].Value = "";

            }
            if (Request.Cookies["fbFirstName"] != null)
            {
                Request.Cookies["fbFirstName"].Expires = DateTime.Now;
                Request.Cookies["fbFirstName"].Value = "";
            }
            FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignOut(true);
        }


        //return Redirect(returnUrl);
        return View();
    }
```

and in my view i am checking for cookies like this

```
    @if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UserCookie"] != null && HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UserCookie"].Value != "")
            {
}


 else if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["fbFirstName"] != null && HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["fbFirstName"].Value != "")
            {
             }
```

but its not clearing i guess its showing empty string "" for the cookie value in the controller but i donno whats happening in view.

is there any thing that i am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Request.Cookies` is used to read the cookies that have come to the server from the client. If you want to *set* cookies, you need to use `Response.Cookies` so the server sends the cookie information the server response.

Try modifying your code to use `Response.Cookies` instead of `Request.Cookies` when you are trying to unset the cookies.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Mean while i have over tried, got a solution that worked though if (this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("UserCookie"))
                {
                    HttpCookie cookie = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["UserCookie"];
                    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                    this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                }